# Template engines for java that support html5

Tags: java, html, spring, velocity, template-engine

I'm working in a spring mvc project and i want to use a template engine i originally choose apache velocity because a slideshare presentation that says it was two times faster than thymeleaf ( http://www.slideshare.net/jreijn/comparing-templateenginesjvm page 41)and since i'm working with big tables i need to use a fast template engine, does apache velocity supports HTML5 if not is there other template engine that supports HTML5 that is not thymeleaf.

***EDIT:***

I was confused about how a template engine works and how can a ide show HTML 5 errrors. thnks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by "supports HTML 5".

Velocity is a general java template engine and supports basically every textual output format you desire.

So if you write "HTML 5" compliant templates and do proper HTML escaping, Velocity will generate "HTML 5" compliant output. I am not sure that any "special" support is needed for "HTML 5" as opposed to other HTML versions or XML, but I might be wrong.

Comment: ok thanks, i was confused about how a  template engine works  and how can a ide show HTML 5 errrors